# How do I access dcim folder on iphone?

Tags: iphone, photo

I connected My iphone to ubuntu and selected do nothing. The iphone was unlocked. I then unplugged the iphone and olugged it in again and eversince I am getting a Folder named “Documents on iphone” having names of some installed apps, instead of proper dcim folder explorer. How do I access dcim

Comment: Open a File Explorer and do a search for the DCIM folder. It most probably be in the root of your SD card or in the root of the internal storage (depending where you store your pictures).

Comment: Iphones dont carry SD cards and normally open dcim folder upon connecting to a computer. In short, they behave as a digital camera for importing photos to computer.

Comment: Doesn't iphones open as mass storage device? Don't you have some file explorer on your iphone and can't find the location of those photos (DCIM folder) for yourself? If you don't know how to use a File Explorer to browse the structure of an operating system, then you should definitively stick to your iphone and never try 'complicated' stuff like Ubuntu!

Comment: Im sorry if i didn't Explain myself precisely. I am able to access the dcim folder on my iphone. I know the path to it. The problem is that ubuntu os recognizes my iphone as [document thing] and it presents iphone in the file explorer with above mentioned name. Folders instead of dcim are names of some apps I've installed on iphone. Inside each folder, are files of the app. Its just like itunes app sharing tab. Also I did search the file explorer(ubuntu) to no avail I hope that made sense. I appreciate your time and help.

Comment: After connecting iphone to Ubuntu, open Nautilus. In the left-side pane a new name should appear in the Devices list. That's you iphone (even if the actual name might differ). Click on that name. Nautilus will open the root of the iphone. Browse carefully till you find the DCIM folder or use the Search box to find it.

Comment: You explained yourself perfectly well, ipse lute clearly doesn't have the slightest clue what he's talking about: rude and ignorant are quite a combo. My guess is you updated to iOS 10. GnuTLS, the crypto protocol dependency used in libimobiledevice, does not work with iOS 10. There is no official workaround yet, so in official terms: Ubuntu doesn't work with iOS 10. If you want to try to hack your way around it, some people have had success compiling libimobiledevice from source using other crypto protocols, but that's all I can say.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/928751/840187) solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 9):

Hi The following worked for me. I plugged in the iphone on my machine.
`5.4.0-90-generic #101-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 15 20:00:55 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`.

I unlock my phone.

On nautilus I see two mounted partitions. One says "Iphone" the other ones that says "Documents on Andres Iphone".

The one that says "Documents (...) " shows some programme folders in my case chrome. But to actually get to the DCIM I will press CTL+L which shoes the path something like this :

`afc://aeb93daaaa2a8271e17848c8e0a0dc783bc4ad95:3/`

All I do is remove **:3/** and then I see all the folders.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for this great solution!

Comment: This answer also works for me as well. Thanks

Comment: After an iOS 17 upgrade, the DCIM folder suddenly stopped showing on my Ubuntu laptop. The Documents on iPhone folder was there. This answer did the trick for me. Thanks