# How do I access iOS camera pictures on Ubuntu?

Tags: iphone, ios

The `libimobiledevice` shipped with 17.04 is actually compatible with the latest iOS. When you connect a device, two virtual devices show up. However, the one with the documents works but the one for the camera **just shows an empty folder.**

There is no obvious way to access the camera pictures on the iOS device.

How do I access them? I don't want to compile `libimobiledevice` from source.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

## Ubuntu 18.04 and later

> Tested on Ubuntu 21.10 and iOS 14.7

This version of Ubuntu has the latest libimobiledevice (at the time of release) so it supports iOS 11.4. There is a propblem with the Gnome integration, though. It shows the Documents folder (app folders). In addition to the tip below by @diego, here's a simple way to get to the pictures folder (this works if the iOS Documents show up for you but not the pictures):

- Open the iDevices Documents folder in Nautilus.
- Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to get the real address which will look like `afc://YOURSERIAL:3/`
- Remove trailing colon and number and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (i.e. it should just read `afc://YOURSERIAL`)

You should now see your iDevices system folders, including DCIM. If you need to access these folders from the command line, you can find them in `$XDG_RUNTIME_DIR/gvfs` (this [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1159685/1736) for a more detailed explanation).

## Historical workaround

As a workaround, you can mount your iOS device with ifuse.

```
sudo apt install ifuse
```

Now connect your device and make sure it is paired with your computer.

```
idevicepair validate
```

If you get a *SUCCESS* message, you are good, if not run `idevicepair pair`. Now you can use ifuse to mount your iOS images folder:

```
mkdir ~/pics && ifuse ~/pics
```

The images are now available in your $HOME folder under *pics*. Ready to be synced with Shotwell. To unmount the folder, use fusermount:

```
fusermount -u ~/pics && rmdir ~/pics
```

> **Note:** in this example I create a *pics* folder and **remove** it afterwards. If you already have a folder named like this, choose a different name.

Comment: After  `ifuse ~/pics` i get
`Failed to connect to lockdownd service on the device.`
`Try again. If it still fails try rebooting your device` But the device is not locked. (I have Ubuntu 17.04 and IOS 11.0.3)

Comment: It's a bug in libimobiledevice that had been fixed in the newest version. I'm working on getting the update into Ubuntu.

Comment: @mniess any ETA?

Comment: @argoneus just upgraded to 17.10 to see if that works. I'll report back here. If not I'll make a preliminary PPA and propose a package upgrade for 17.10.

Comment: Worked for me with 17.10 and an ipad 2 running iOS9.3.5 (have to unlock it before pairing, hit "Trust" when asked) - thanks!

Comment: Super useful, thank you! Just worked for me on ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and iphone 8 with ios 13.6.

Comment: IFUSE solution was the only one that worked for me in Ubuntu 20.04 and Iphone XR iOS 13.5. 
libimobiledevice-utils also worked but was slower and failed many times when copying videos (MOV files actually).

Comment: Thanks! This works for my iPhone 12 on iOS 14.5 with Linux Ubuntu 20.10.

Comment: Is there any way to navigate to this location on the command line?

Comment: @MRule I updated the answer with more details on how to do that.

Comment: This also seems to resolve this -7 I/O problem error described at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611543/got-error-getting-file-7-i-o-problem-on-one-file-i-guess-while-transferri with an iPhone 7 and Linux Mint 20.2.  Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

If you see the serial number of your iPhone as a result of

```
dmesg|grep SerialNumber:
```

then you can use the hotkey Ctrl-L in Files and point it to

```
afc://YOURSERIALNUMBER/DCIM
```

where the iPhone photos reside.

I did not have to create or mount any extra folders.

Comment: See also this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1396243/407637

Answer (score 2):

On Debian, I had to install the `gvfs-backends` package which contains `gvfs-afc`, the backend for *iPhone/iPod*:

```
apt install gvfs-backends
```

Then open a socket for your iPhone:

```
# /usr/sbin/usbmuxd -u -v -f -U your_user_name
```

Then as said by Diego and mniess, get your iphone serial number:

```
dmesg|grep SerialNumber:
```

then open thunar and go to:

```
afc://41879faab42214e1026672589a3cb5dfa6aab7a3/PhotoData/CPLAssets/
```

replacing `41879faab42214e1026672589a3cb5dfa6aab7a3` by yours

Answer (score 1):

These steps from https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=424727#c7 worked for me to make Ubuntu see the photos on an iPhone:

**On the iPhone:**

1. Turn **off** Wi-Fi.
2. Turn **off** Bluetooth.
3. Turn **on** Personal Hotspot.
4. After all of the above, connect the iPhone to the Ubuntu machine with a USB cable.

**NOTES:**

- When you are asked how Personal Hotspot should connect, choose "USB Only".
- When you are asked whether to trust the computer, choose "Trust".

Answer (score 0):

Running 18.04 I just could connect the iPhone, enter the Code (just the normal iPhone un-lock code), and the device was mounted, and can be searched used Nautilus (the normal folder manager) or the showtell App.

Everything pre-installed.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.04. At first try in Nautilus Empty Folder but finally it works.