# When using fusermount to access photos on an iphone, what folder should the photos be in?

Tags: iphone, photo-management

I am trying to access the photos and videos on my iphone 6, running iOS 10.3.3 from my computer running Ubuntu Gnome 17.04.  I followed the procedure written up by "mniess" on this question: [How do I access iOS camera pictures on Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928750/how-do-i-access-ios-camera-pictures-on-ubuntu-17-04)

Everything went smoothly, my phone mounted and I got a list of folders with all kinds of data, but I can't find my photos.  I found my music, and album covers and a bunch of app data but not photos.

Any advice I what I should be looking for would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you notice any error message after `mkdir ~/pics && ifuse ~/pics`?  If so please post [edit] and post it.