# Can't veiw files/photos from iPhone on 16.04. Unmounting doesn't help

Tags: iphone, shotwell

I have an iPhone 5s running iOS 11.0.3. When I connect the phone to my computer running Ubuntu 16.04, I select "Trust" on the phone screen, and it automatically mounts in Ubuntu. When I open the window, it says there are digital photos on the device, but the window shows no files. When I look at properties of the device, it shows 25.4 GB used, but states the "contents" as "nothing". When I open shotwell the iPhone appears as a device, but I get "Could not claim the USB device (-53)", and "Unable to fetch previews from the camera: I/O problem (-7)".

If I unmount the phone, nothing seems to change in Shotwell.

I have looked at a lot of other questions, but they all seem to either be asking how to mount the phone at all, or the problem is fixed by unmounting. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This answer worked for me https://askubuntu.com/a/928751/684030

I had all the same errors you were so I had to

`sudo apt install ifuse`

`sudo apt install libimobiledevice-utils`

`idevicepair pair`

`idevicepair validate`

When I got the success after validate I still had to create a directory in my home directory called pics (as shown in answer linked above) then

`ifuse pics`

You can now navigate to the pics directory to find your pictures

you have to unmount the folder after so you can use
`fusermount -u ~/pics && rmdir ~/pics`

Comment: in case one get `No device found, is it plugged in?` run `systemctl restart usbmuxd.service`