# Pictures and documents on Iphone no longer showing up

Tags: iphone, shotwell

My Iphone shows up as an empty folder. It has worked in the past, but now I can't seen to find a way to get to my photo's anymore.
Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Iphone 8 - version 14.4

Does anyone know where to start with this issue?

Thank you!

Comment: Same configuration. Photo works normal with nautilus file manager. Shotwell does not work ("device is locked/busy"). And the are not access for documents in Nautilus at all.

Answer (score 1):

To anyone out there and to my future self in a couple of months, this is how I solved it:

more searching brought me to try this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1159559/1063723

And then I did a mass convert of the .HEIC images through this:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1108325/1063723

Would be nice if it were a bit easier...