# Iphone Photo folder appears once and disappear after reconnect

Tags: 18.04, iphone

I am trying to copy images to my local drive on Ubuntu 18.04. First time when I plug in my phone, it shows "Documents on iPhone" and a camera icon. After unplug, and plug back in the photos and camera icon is gone.
I followed this [Thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2376741) and use command

> sudo usbmuxd -u -U usbmux

after that I unplug and plug again. The folder  "Documents on iPhone" is back, but not the camera icon where I can access and copy images out.

Does anyone how to resolve this?

Thanks

Tinh Lac

Comment: This is a duplicate of
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1044679/iphone-mounts-only-once-doesnt-show-pictures-documents-on-remount/1048263, I posted the solution there.

Answer (score 4):

I found a solution

first restart USB by command

> sudo usbmuxd -u -U usbmux

then going into the phone folder (file) using nautilus and press

> CTRL+L

to get the usb serial number. Delete colon and number at the end. It will direct to iPhone storage. In that directory navigate to DCIM directory. This is where all photos saved.

preference: [How do I access iOS camera pictures on Ubuntu 17.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928750/how-do-i-access-ios-camera-pictures-on-ubuntu-17-04)