# No visible files with ifuse ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mount, iphone, ios

Downloaded `ifuse`, made a folder, ran a command

```
ifuse ~/my_folder`
```

The folder appeared empty. Ran the command again.

Got the message:

> fuse: mountpoint is not empty

But still nothing visible. Looked at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/928750/how-do-i-access-ios-camera-pictures-on-ubuntu) forum.

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in my finder just shows a regular path. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in ifuse with ubuntu 20.04
https://github.com/libimobiledevice/ifuse/issues/63